# c++ Convert hexa to ASCII before send with the serial port

Tags: c++, ascii

I want to communicate with an electronic Load in C++. I use win32.h. To put the electronic load in remote control, I need to send :

"AA 00 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CB"

But before to send, I need to convert it in ASCII code.

My code is :

```
 HANDLE hCom;
 DWORD dwError;
 BOOL fSuccess;
 DWORD dwEvtMask;
 int i;
 int NbOctet;
 char *Message;
 unsigned long nBytesWrite;
LPCWSTR Port = L"COM14";
 Message = new char[200];
std::string Test;
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/* Ouverture du port de communiucation           */
/*-----------------------------------------------*/

hCom = CreateFile(Port,
   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
   0,
   NULL,
   OPEN_EXISTING,
   0,
   NULL
   );

Message = "AA 00 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CB";

NbOctet = strlen(Message);

WriteFile(hCom,Message,NbOctet,&nBytesWrite,NULL);


CloseHandle(hCom);


delete[] Message;
```

My question is : How I can convert Message in ASCII caracter before to send it?

I have an example in python of what i want :

```
# Construct a set to remote command
cmd = chr(0xaa) + chr(0x00) + chr(0x20) # First three bytes
cmd += chr(0x01) + chr(0x00)*(length_packet - 1 - 4)
cmd += chr(CalculateChecksum(cmd))

sp.write(cmd)
```

---

My new code is :

```
void main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
 HANDLE hCom;
 DWORD dwError;
 BOOL fSuccess;
 DWORD dwEvtMask;
 int i;
 int NbOctet;
 unsigned long nBytesWrite;
 LPCWSTR Port = L"\\\\.\\COM14";

 /*-----------------------------------------------*/
 /* Ouverture du port de communiucation           */
 /*-----------------------------------------------*/

 hCom = CreateFile(Port,
   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
   0,
   NULL,
   OPEN_EXISTING,
   0,
   NULL
   );

char Message[] = {0xAA,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xCB};

NbOctet = strlen(Message);
qDebug() << Message;
WriteFile(hCom,Message,NbOctet,&nBytesWrite,NULL);


CloseHandle(hCom);

}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: The string `"AA 00 ..."` already *is* in ASCII. The character `'A'` is the same as the integer value `65`. Sending that string will send the ASCII values `65 65 32 48 48" etc.

Comment: Also, your program contain undefined behavior, in that you allocate memory, then *overwrite* the pointer (making it point to a literal string), so the `delete` will most likely crash.

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to tread each space-delimited value in the string as a hexadecimal number, and send the actual numbers as integer values?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to send ASCII code. Actually, I try to convert the python code that you can see in my post in c++ code

Comment: `NbOctet` is 1. Consider using a debugger.

Comment: Your new code is good, except that you use `strlen` which searches for the string terminator `'\0'` (which is equal to zero), and when it's found in the second place in the array it returns the length `1`. Use `sizeof(Message)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use hex I wouldn't recommend using hex strings at all. You can do the following instead:

```
char message_bytes[] = {0xAA, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
int message_length = 7; /* determine the size using either an argument or manually */
```

Also your open file function will fail because when the COM numbers go > 9 you need to do the following for windows to recognise them:

```
LPCWSTR Port = L"\\\\.\\COM14";
```

As described in [This Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831)

---

You arn't setting your COM port up properly, consider doing using [DCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [BuildCommDCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then using [SetcommState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
DCB portConfig;
memset(&portConfig, 0, sizeof(portConfig));
portConfig.DCBlength = sizeof(portConfig);
/* 9600 baud, Even parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit */
BuildCommDCB(TEXT("9600,E,8,1"), &portConfig); 
SetCommState(hCom, &portConfig);
```

Make sure you set the port up to be the same as your hardware. Please note that while I haven't included error checking, I highly recommend that you do.

Comment: You pretty much forgot to answer the question.

Comment: @IInspectable I answered the question by saying "don't do this use this method instead", I don't think he should be encouraged to use the method he is using.

Comment: thank you for you response, I try to apply your tips in my code but it doesn't work again. I put my new code in the question

Comment: @boboch The `NbOctet = strlen(Message);` will not work, you will have to define the size yourself, in this case `NbOctet = 25;` You also didn't set the com port up properly. You will probably need to get your com port working before thinking of sending messages through it. I'll post some code.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because BuildCommDCB want two argument. So i try this :

    DCB *portConfig;

But when I execute my code, the application crash.
    fSuccess = BuildCommDCB(L"9600,N,8,1",portConfig); /* 9600baud, Even parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit */
    fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, portConfig);

Comment: @boboch Sorry about that, I got the function wrong for `BuildCommDCB` and `SetCommState`, The code in the answer has been tested now and will compile and run.

Comment: Thank you, the code compile correctly but the function SetCommState doesn't work correctly :                                                                      DCB portConfig;

When i run the programm, it pass in the condition if
    BuildCommDCB(TEXT("9600,N,8,1"), &portConfig); /* 9600 baud, Even parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit */
    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &portConfig);

     if (!fSuccess)
      {
         qDebug()<<"problem";
      }

Comment: Unfortunatly we can't move this to chat, what error number is `SetCommState` returning?

Comment: I don't know i can find the error number but the program pass in the if condition so I deduce that an error occur when i try to set the port

Comment: Ah I see what you have done, please read the documentation provided. It says `If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.` meaning if there is no error then your if statement will succeed. You're checking for the opposite of what you should be. You can also use `GetLastError` to get the last error.

Comment: The function return 0,so i have a problem with this instruction

Comment: I misread your if statment, sorry again, Use the following to print out the error: `{ qDebug() << GetLastError(); }`

Comment: When i use GetLastError, the function return 87 which signify : The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: I think I found it, I forgot to tell you to do `portConfig.DCBlength = sizeof(portConfig);` right after the `DCB portConfig;` line. This may be causing the issue.

Comment: I also forgot to tell you to clear the dcb memory using `memset(&portConfig, 0, sizeof(portConfig));` before setting the dcb length.

Comment: Now, thanks to you, i can communicate with the electronic load but the message which is send is ?. I see that the communication arrive to the electronic load because on it, a message "link" appear when the program run but anything happen. I think I have a problem with the message format

Comment: If you are able to view the output of your com device, try passing in "hello world" as the message and see what comes out, also make sure to specify the message length correctly. You may be using the wrong configuration settings for your com device, or it could be a wiring issue. Is your device RS-232?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to get the separate values into strings, and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to parse the string as integer:

```
std::ostringstream os("AA 00 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CB");

std::vector<uint8_t> values;

std::string value_string;
while (os >> value_string)
    values.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(std::stoi(value_string, nullptr, 16)));

WriteFile(hCom, values.data(), sizeof(uint8_t) * values.size(), &nBytesWrite, NULL);
```

Comment: Thats a nice piece of code! But I don't think he should be encouraged to take this path for what he want's to do.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Unless there is a pressing need to represent the message in this format, this method is quite wasteful and far from a standard way of passing a message into a COM port. The OP is obviously just beginning to use COM ports so it's best to give him good habits.